# VBA gives error Run-time '-2147352571 Excel when filling a text area

Tags: excel, vba, windows

im trying to make a form that shows info from cells, but when i enter a search, it gives this error.
I think it's because there are problems with the data types, but i don't know how to fix it, probably problem with the date field, as far as i could investigate.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    TextBox1.Enabled = ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1
End Sub

'add a listobject datarow range to a listbox
Private Sub RowToList(rw As Range, lst As MSForms.ListBox)
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    lst.AddItem
    r = UBound(lst.List, 1)
    For i = 1 To rw.Cells.Count
        lst.List(r, i - 1) = rw.Cells(i)
    Next i
End Sub

'this is the one place to edit the source listobject
Private Function SourceList() As ListObject
    Set SourceList = Hoja1.ListObjects("TablaPrincipal")
End Function

'clear a listbox
Private Sub ClearList(lst As MSForms.ListBox)
    If Len(lst.RowSource) > 0 Then
        lst.RowSource = ""
    Else
        lst.Clear
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim rw As Range, v, lo As ListObject, i As Long
    Dim colNum As Long
    
    Set lo = SourceList
    v = Me.TextBox1.Value
    ClearList Me.Lista
    
    If Len(v) > 0 Then 'any search term?
        colNum = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1 'which column are we searching on?
        For Each rw In lo.DataBodyRange.Rows
            If UCase(rw.Cells(colNum).Value) Like "*" & UCase(v) & "*" Then 'check the relavant column
                RowToList rw, Me.Lista
            End If
        Next rw
    Else
        Me.Lista.RowSource = lo 'no search term: reload the whole table
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.Lista.RowSource = SourceList
    Me.Lista.ColumnCount = SourceList.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count 'dynamic
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim myList As ListObject, ListHeaders As Range
    Dim Headers() As String, i As Long
    Set myList = SourceList
    Set ListHeaders = myList.HeaderRowRange
    ReDim Headers(ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1
        Headers(i) = ListHeaders.Cells(i + 1)
    Next
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Headers
End Sub
```

Here are some images of the excel and error itself:
[image: The Excel table]
[image: The form without the error, showing everything of the table]
[image: The error]
[image: Debugger]

I hope anyone can help me fix this problem please, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific row that fails to load?  What's the value of `i` when it fails?  Also what is `rw.Address` ?

Comment: Hey, every row fails, also the value of i = 1 when it fails, and i don't see any rw.Address, do you mean rw.cells? that's the url, the first column

Comment: Can you share a workbook which shows the problem?

Comment: i'm sorry but what do you mean? I uploaded pictures, what do you mean by workbook?

Comment: workbook = your Excel file   With enough content to reproduce the problem you're seeing.   And preferably without any not-relevant code.